# Direct proof of: $\#($cover of $V) < \#F \; \Rightarrow \;V$ belongs to cover

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm looking for a ***direct*** proof <sup>1</sup> (as opposed to a proof-by-contradiction) of the following theorem:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and let $\mathcal{W}$ be a collection of (vector) subspaces of $V$ such that $\bigcup \mathcal{W} = V$.  (I.e. $\mathcal{W}$ *"covers"*, or *"is a cover of"*, $V$.)
>
> Then,
>
> $$\#\mathcal{W} < \#F \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\;\; V \in \mathcal{W}.$$
>
> <sub>(*EDIT: After posting I learned from one of the comments that **the statement above is false** in general.  Please see comments for more info.*)</sub>

FWIW, I have a direct proof of this theorem that works (I think) when $\#\mathcal{W}$ is *finite*, but I don't know how to extend it to the general case.  I include this proof below, but please don't infer from this that this question is asking for a patch for my proof.  An entirely different direct proof will do just as well.

NB: I've seen this theorem usually stated in the following somewhat less general form: if the ground field $F$ is infinite, then no *finite* collection $\mathcal{W}$ of *proper* subspaces of $V$ can cover $V$.

---

The theorem is trivially true if $\dim(V) = 0$, so assume that $\dim(V) > 0$, and pick some non-zero subspace $W \in \mathcal{W}$.  Also, define $\mathcal{W}^{\,\prime}$ as the reduced collection $\mathcal{W}\backslash \{W\}$.

If $W = V$, there's nothing left to prove.  Therefore, assume $W \neq V$, and pick vectors $x \in W\backslash \{0\}$, and $y \in V\backslash W$.  Define the set

$$L = \{x + \alpha y \;|\; \alpha \in F^{\times} \}\;$$

where $F^{\times}$ denotes the set of units of $F$, i.e. $F^{\times} = F\backslash \{0\}$.

The definition of $L$ implies that $L \subset V\backslash W \subset \bigcup \mathcal{W}^{\,\prime}$, since $y$ was explicitly chosen to be outside of $W$.  The immediate goal now is to show that $L$ intersects some subspace in $\mathcal{W}^{\,\prime}$ in at least two distinct points.

The map from $F^{\times}$ to $L$ implied by the definition of $L$, namely $\alpha \mapsto x + \alpha y$, is clearly surjective; it is also injective, because $y \in V\backslash W \supset V\backslash \{0\}$ is non-zero.  Therefore, it follows that

$$\#L = \#F^{\times} = \#F - 1\;.$$

Now, to prove the theorem's assertion, assume that $\#\mathcal{W} < \#F$.  This, together with the equality above, give:

$$\#\mathcal{W}^{\,\prime} = \#\mathcal{W} - 1 < \#F - 1 = \#L\;,$$

and it follows from the pigeonhole principle that no map assigning vectors in $L$ to subspaces in $\mathcal{W}^{\,\prime}$ can be injective.  In particular, there must be a subspace $W_x \in \mathcal{W}^{\,\prime}$ such that

$$\#(W_x \cap L) \geq 2\;.$$

Therefore, let $x + \alpha_0 y$ and $x + \alpha_1 y$ be distinct vectors in such subspace $W_x \in \mathcal{W}^{\,\prime}$.  Then it follows that $\alpha_0 \neq \alpha_1$, and that by subtracting the first vector from the second, and dividing the result by $\alpha_1 - \alpha_0$, we get that $y \in W_x$, and therefore also that $x \in W_x$.

Since $x$ was an arbitrary vector in $W\backslash\{0\}$, this argument shows that $W\backslash\{0\} \subset \bigcup \mathcal{W}^{\,\prime}$, and, since $\{0\}$ is a subset of every subspace of $V$, it follows that

$$W \subset \bigcup \mathcal{W}^{\,\prime} \;.$$

Therefore the collection $\mathcal{W}^{\,\prime}$, which is strictly smaller than the original collection $\mathcal{W}$, also covers $V$.

It is at this point that I have a hard time keeping the argument agnostic as to the cardinality of $\mathcal{W}$.  If I assume that $\#\mathcal{W}$ is finite, then it is clear that the argument above can be applied a finite number of times to produce a monotonically decreasing *sequence* of *finite* covers of $V$.  From this it follows that $V$ is one of the subspaces included in the original cover $\mathcal{W}$, as the theorem asserts.

I note that since the choice of $W$ was arbitrary (among the non-trivial subspaces of $\mathcal{W}$), it follows from the argument above that *every* subspace belonging to $\mathcal{W}$ is contained in the union of all the *other* subspaces in $\mathcal{W}$.  This is a tantalizing observation, but I can't figure out how to conclude from it that $V$ must be one of the subspaces belonging to $\mathcal{W}$.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>I don't quite know why this is, but I usually find a direct proof a lot more illuminating than the corresponding proof-by-contradiction, even when the latter is much shorter/slicker.</sub>

Comment: Is there anything of interest to you at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26/can-a-vector-space-over-an-infinite-field-be-a-finite-union-of-proper-subspaces ?

Comment: I think you must be reading this note of mine:http://math.uga.edu/~pete/coveringnumbersv2.pdf.  (You recently commented on an MO answer of mine which was, in its entirety, a link to this note.)  However...the assertion that you have boxed is not true, as the main result of my note makes clear.  In particular, any infinite-dimensional vector space over a field can be covered by $\aleph_0$ subspaces, so if $\operatorname{dim} V$ is infinite and $\# F > \aleph_0$ (e.. $F = \mathbb{R}$) then your assertion is false.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: yes I'm reading your note.  Apparently, I don't entirely understand it.  Time for a re-read.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: yes, of course, I see it now.  I had mistakenly imagined that your note went over the extension of the finite-dimensional version (of the boxed theorem) to the infinite-dimensional case, and I failed to notice that it does the opposite.